# How does the copper experience pig work?

Tags: naruto-online

The copper experience pig increases other ninja tool experience, but what exactly does that mean? As far as I can tell, ninja tools can only gain experience through combining like items. Does buying this item just instantly raise all ninja tools by X amount?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I searched on the Naruto Online forums, the copper pig give you **instantly** 60 xp, atleast the last events gave you that amount of xp, and it is a perfect way to level up the ninja tools.
There are not much information but I found a little bit.

[Source xp](http://forum.naruto.oasgames.com/en/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=7927&extra=)

[Source what copper pigs do](http://forum.naruto.oasgames.com/en/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=2132&extra=&page=2)